# WAMP3.1.3: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /sitename on this server

Tags: apache, wamp

Apache version -2.4.33

PHP version - 7.2.4

I set up a virtualhost and site in WAMP. I am able to load the page on that machine without issue.

When I try to access it from my machine (I can ping the WAMP server without issue). I get the following:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /sitename on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) PHP/7.2.4 Server at XXX.XX.XX.XXX Port 80

As far as I can tell, my configuration is set up correctly:

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitename
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/sitename"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp/www/sitename/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
...
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Could someone help point out why I am not able to access this?